# Moving one agent within another agent in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am making simple distribution center in Anylogic.I did make truck agent and i am able to move it from one gis point to another gis point.

But I want to load some other agents(Let's say banana agent) into my truck agent and then trucks start their journey(if truck is full of banana).How can i do this?

Comment: the truck is an agent. You can create models inside the agent, which in this case would be source->sink moving bananas to the truck.
I would do something of the sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you have already solved your problem from almost a year ago. However, since there is no specific answer, I'll leave it here for anyone who might get stuck with the same problem.

Anylogic's **Process Modelling Library** (PML) has an element called **Pickup** and its opposite, **Dropoff**. This is used to do exactly what you asked: to load some element into a transporter (either a truck, a forklift, or even a person).

To use the block as you asked you would need a topology like in the picture:
[image: topology]

The **Queue** elements are necessary to hold elements until the pickup occurs. 
The **Pickup** element might pick elements in three modes:

- While a given condition is True;
- An exact amount (if available);
- All available agents.

I'm assuming all trucks **must** be completely filled up to its maximum capacity. Hence, the chosen mode will be the second one where the exact amount will be *TruckCapacity*, a parameter of agent ***Truck***.
The selected mode picks up agents (in this case Bananas) up to the desired amount. However, if nothing is available or the present amount is inferior to the desired, the native behavior of the **Pickup** block is to allow the *container* element to simply go through it and pick only what's available.

To prevent such behavior, I've created a restricted area where only 1 *Truck* can be at a time. Additionally, the **Hold** block *WaitFullyLoaded* (set to initially blocked) forces the container agent *Truck* to be fully loaded. Whenever a *Banana* enters the **Queue** *waitTruck*, a verification is performed to check if 1 *Truck* can be filled. If so, allows passage for that one truck:

```
if(self.size()/TruckCapacity>=1){
    WaitFullyLoaded.unblock();
}
```

To block *WaitFullyLoaded* again, when the truck passes through the ***restrictedAreaEnd*** block, it performs `WaitFullyLoaded.block();`

The main idea is this. However, many features can be added and changed.

Hope this helps,

Luís